# Web form frameworks in Java

Tags: java, forms, groovy, web

What are commonly used ways to build web forms in Java and Groovy?

Spring and Grails provide corresponding taglibs, but I am wondering whether there are form frameworks, which allow to create forms as sets of objects, dynamically manipulate the elements, embed sub-forms, populate and validate, and render.

For example, if I have a group of fields common for a number of forms, I would like to reuse the code. Furthermore, such a group of elements, in turn, may be a part of another group. I also would like to dynamically reorder the elements, change field names and other input field attributes, and so on without altering any HTML code.

Answer (score 2):

You can try open-source [Formio library](http://www.formio.net). It can be used in many environments/frameworks and with various template frameworks.

With Formio, you can manipulate forms using objects: Create form definitions - mappings, definitions of form fields and nested mappings (for nested objects like person's address or list of addresses). Both mappings and form fields can be defined as reusable (immutable) objects and composed together. You can use nested mappings to model reusable "groups" of form fields (and to nest them into another groups).

Formio supports binding of data from Java object to form definition that can be then passed to a template and rendered. Data from the request can be validated (using bean validation API) and bound back to the Java object (to newly created instance or to provided one). Binding of basic Java types, nested object types, collections or arrays (of primitives or complex objects) is supported. Immutable classes can be used.

Form definition can be prepopulated with data (before passing to the template) and filled back with (validated) data from the request. Automatic bidirectional data binding is implemented in "fill" and "bind" methods on the form definition object.

Formio is server-centric library, but can be combined with existing client-side libraries. Rendering is left to the template system. For example, using JSP you can prepare your own reusable tags to render form definition populated with data and its parts (nested mappings, various types of form fields) which already contain all neccessary data to render, including flags like visible, enabled, readonly, required. You can define your own custom field attributes and use them in reusable tags/template snippets so the HTML code need not to be altered in most cases.

Note: I am author of the library, you can find the sources on the GitHub and make your fork. Check the documentation for further details.

Comment: As this is self-advertisement (yes, I checked the github repo), you must add a disclaimer to your answer stating you are the author / contributor.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a templating/layout framework which will allow you to reuse snippets of code.

In the java web dev space, [Tiles](http://tiles.apache.org) is the de facto framework for layouts. Both Grails and Spring MVC support Tiles.

Comment: A template engine can be used as a view layer for a form framework, but just splitting the markup into reusable blocks is not sufficient. It won't be easy to reuse form element decorations. Validation and relation between elements shall then exist somewhere else. Not to mention that it won't anyhow allow to dynamically change the from dynamically accroring to business logic.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't come across an MVC framework that would expose a complete interface to handling form data as objects, in both ways. There is always some manual coding that is required to translate form data into objects, and back.

There are alternative frameworks, like Echo (http://echo.nextapp.com/site/) that completely isolate the application from dealings with requests and responses, they may be more suited for the kind of abstraction you are looking for.